# Apps Script Automatic timestamp when a tab gets updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

So I'm trying to create a script that can apply to several tabs in my spreadsheet file and will automatically update the timestamp in each individual tab when something in that tab is updated/changed. The cell that I want the timestamp in is different in each tab. I thought I had it working but after not touching the file for two days and returning to it, I found that it's no longer updating. Can anyone take a look and see where the issue is? Also, any idea why it would have been working for two days and then stopped working without any edits to the script? I'm new to  java so appreciate any help. Here's the current script I'm using:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 1') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 1")
    ss.getRange("F3").setValue(new Date())}
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 2') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 2")
    ss.getRange("L3").setValue(new Date())}
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 3') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 3")
    ss.getRange("K4").setValue(new Date())}
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 4') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 4")
    ss.getRange("K4").setValue(new Date())}
}
```

Is there a different way I should be approaching the script for this?

Comment: Are your sheets named `Sheet 1` etc. with a space, or are they defaulted to the automatic naming which would be `Sheet1` etc. with no space? Also unrelated, but the block `e.source.getSheetByName(...)` isn't doing anything in this function and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for `Sheet 1` etc. with a space in it, when the default Sheets naming convention is `Sheet1` without a space.

Try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    ss.getRange("F3").setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (ss.getName() == "Sheet2") {
    ss.getRange("L3").setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (ss.getName() == "Sheet3") {
    ss.getRange("K4").setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (ss.getName() == "Sheet4") {
    ss.getRange("K4").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Additionally, there are some code-style improvements you can make:

- `e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet X")` is not being used, you can remove that entirely.
- You can set `date` to a variable, e.g. `const date = new Date()`
- Use `switch/case` to improve readability
- Don't use `var` unless you absolutely have to; use `let` for mutable variables, or in this case, `const` because they do not mutate.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly and appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ["Sheet 1","Sheet 2","Sheet 3","Sheet 4"];
  const locs = ["F3","L3","K4","K4"];
  let idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx) {
    sh.geRange(locs[idx]).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Remember onEdit only triggers on user edits

Answer (score 0):

Your script has a couple of inefficiencies and unnecessary lines of code, but let's first address the main issues:

Variable Scope: You are using `ss` as the active sheet but also trying to get the sheet by name via `e.source.getSheetByName(...)`, which is redundant.

Event Object: You're not using the event object `e` effectively, which provides you with all the details related to the edit event.

Here is a different (and hopefully more optimized version) of the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  
  // Use a switch statement to handle different sheet names
  switch(sheetName) {
    case 'Sheet 1':
      sheet.getRange('F3').setValue(new Date());
      break;
    case 'Sheet 2':
      sheet.getRange('L3').setValue(new Date());
      break;
    case 'Sheet 3':
      sheet.getRange('K4').setValue(new Date());
      break;
    case 'Sheet 4':
      sheet.getRange('K4').setValue(new Date());
      break;
  }
}
```